# custom gwt editable celltable

Tags: gwt

I would like to create Custom Gwt Celltable with editable columns, where each column may accept any type of widget, is there way to do it, please let me know?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Cell system, by design, does not allow widgets to be added inside of a Cell. This is the point of the Cell idea - drawing many elements with a single instance, and letting that one instance handle the events for all of them.

This is how the various Cell-based widgets can perform better than the FlexTable or Grid, which allow widgets.

The closest you can get is to draw a Widget on some event sent to the Cell instance, but even there you must be careful to detach the widget when you are finished with it, or risk a memory leak.